# Will Entity Framework delete tables that it didn't create?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an existing database.  It has tables that were created manually (in SQL, not with EF).  I have to add EF Code First Migrations, for reasons.

When Update-Database is run on an environment that hasn't had its migrations applied yet, I want EF to create the tables, but I DON'T want it to drop the whole database.  Is that what it will do, and if so how can I stop it?

In my database context I'm not sure whether to use

```
//Disable initializer
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(null);
```

or to use

```
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>());
```

According to the documentation it looks like `CreateDatabaseIfNotExists` will actually still drop the database if the EF tables don't exist.

But if I just disable the initializer then I think that means it won't even create the EF tables.  Neither of these solutions seem good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some tables in your db, that created manually, you can enable migration with following commands:

```
PM>Enable-Migrations
PM>AddMigration [A_Name_For_Your_Migration] -IgnoreChanges
PM>Update-Databases
```

Comment: I did not specify a database initialization strategy, and then did as you suggested, and it worked.  Thanks.